# How do I use the list_for_each macro in list.h (from the Linux kernel) properly?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having a hard time using list.h from the Linux kernel to provide linked list functionality for my code. I suspect that I almost have functional code, but I am mixing up pointers somewhere.

How do I use the list_for_each macro properly? In my code, it gets stuck in an infinite loop and does not exit the list. Below is the snippet from my code in which the problem lies (look in the add_kv function):

```
dict_entry *alloc_dict(void)
{
    //allocates the linked list head node
    dict_entry *d = malloc(sizeof(dict_entry));
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&d->list);
    return d;
}
 
void free_dict(dict_entry *d)
{
    //TODO: free each dict_entry struct and their keys and values.
    free(d);
}

int add_kv(dict_entry *d, char *key, char *value)
{
    if(!key || !d) return 0; //if key or d is null, return 0

    struct list_head *p; //serves as the cursor
    dict_entry *entry; //empty dict_entry
    entry = alloc_dict(); //allocate memory for it

    list_for_each(p, &d->list){
        d = list_entry(p, dict_entry, list); //CHANGED TO d FROM entry
        printf("gothere, p = %p\n",p); // something in here is creating an infinite loop. p is moving back and forth. this is the big problem in this code
        if(strcmp(entry->key, key) == 0){
            free(entry->value);
            entry->value = 0;
            entry->value = malloc(strlen(value));
            strcpy(entry->value, value);
            return 1; //how do i get rid of entry?
        }
    }
    //If you haven't returned by now, continue on to add a new entry at the end of the list 
    entry->key = malloc(strlen(key)); //allocate memory for the key
    strcpy(entry->key, key); //copy the key value to the key in the entry
    entry->value = malloc(strlen(value)); //allocate memory for value
    strcpy(entry->value, value); //copy value value to the value in the entry
 
    list_add(&entry->list,&d->list); //tacks the list of the new entry onto the existing list (provided as d)
    return 1;
}
```

Below is the list_for_each macro from list.h, for reference:

```
/**
 * list_for_each    -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop cursor.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

And here is the list_entry macro from list.h, also for reference:

```
/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:    the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:   the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

...and the dict_entry struct I'm using:

```
  6 typedef struct {
  7   char *key;
  8   char *value;
  9   struct list_head list;
 10 }dict_entry;
```

...and when run, this happens:

```
gothere, p = 0x1178050
gothere, p = 0x1178020
gothere, p = 0x1178050
gothere, p = 0x1178020
```

over and over again.

A good explanation on how to implement lists with list.h can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310021226/www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5) for reference.

Comment: How is `dict_entry` defined?

Answer (score 4):

You are reassigning the variable `d` for some reason, and this breaks the `list_for_each` macro.

You have this code:

```
list_for_each(p, &d->list){
    d = list_entry(p, dict_entry, list);
```

The macro reevaluates `&d->list` on each iteration to see when the list end is reached. Since `d` is reassigned, this check fails and it loops forever.

Comment: Before, that code was more sane- it used to be:

`list_for_each(p, &d->list){

    entry = list_entry(p, dict_entry, list)`

But I changed it in a panic to reallocate d because this just prints out one address over and over again - the infinite loop still happens. So, I've edited the code to _not_ reallocate d and I still have a problem with the loop macro.

Comment: I guess here you should use `list_for_each_entry()`